# What is the minimum level for each item rarity and type?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 1, legendary (orange colour-rarity) items can only spawn at level 16 or higher, if not 15. Same with class mods.

In Borderlands 2, apparently orange weapons can now spawn at any level. Earlier ammo vending machines have no rocket launcher ammo to sell, so I presume that no rocket launchers can be found until a certain level.

What is the minimum level for each item type? (Particularly, Vladof rocket launchers?)

Comment: I am pretty sure the minimum is 9 but I have no evidence to back it up though

Comment: For the record, my question was not intended for item rarity solely but all items in general, hence why I mention rocket launchers and class mods. Although, I can see now the close votes reasonings.

Comment: Considering there's a million billion items in BL2, you should probably change the question to how a minimum level an item can appear at is determined, if indeed there is such a restriction.

Comment: I know an answer! Please reopen :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Rarity levels** do not have a minimum item level. It is possible to obtain a Level 1 (or even Level 0!) [Hornet](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hornet_(Borderlands_2)) from Knuckledragger, for example.

**Item types**, on the other hand, are introduced gradually, to avoid overwhelming the player and make him/her better understand their value and differences.
Weapon introduction levels are:

[image]

Source: [Inside the Box article](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1087).

Unfortunately, there's no exact data yet for shields (2? 3?) grenade mods (around 6, first drop from Boom Bewm), relics and class mods (10 or more).

Comment: Is it possible to obtain level 1/0 pearlescents?

Comment: @NiteCyper I'd guess so, assuming you are able to reach whoever drops them at level 1 (and probably not level up during the kill) :-)

Comment: The Wiki says they only spawn in UVHM but for one exception: Tiny Tina's Lootsplosion Slot Machine. And the minimum level of that DLC is lv.30.